# Get a Discord Role by Id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot but just ran into a problem.

I want to modify a role. A specific role. I know how to do that with `edit_role`, but I need to get the Role object to edit it. Now, that's the problem.

How do I *get a Role object by the role's id*? Or can I *use the id in the Role argument*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.utils.get) to loop through `Guild.roles` and get the one you're looking for:

```
from discord.utils import get

role_id = 123
role = get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
```

Comment: is `guild.roles` the same as `message.server.roles` or am i making that up?

Comment: In the rewrite version, server has been renamed to guild, which is what all of the discord documentation calls them.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `Guild.get_role(role_id)` to get the role if you have the id.

```
role_id = 2134532534
role = my_server.get_role(role_id)
```