# Discord.py Looking to remove a role once a user has sent a message

Tags: python, discord.py

As mentioned earlier, I'm trying to remove a role once a user has sent the correct message (i.e.) '&ign [ign]', the role ID is known and I'd like it to target the user that sent the message.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if '&ign ' in message.content:
        ignList=open('registeredIGNs.txt','a')
        IGN=message.content[5:]
        ignList.write(str(IGN)+'\n')
        ignList.close()
        print('IGN added')
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
      #Remove user once IGN recorded
        roleID = 991038550118121602
        await message.author.remove_roles(roleID)
    else:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Any help would be nice :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a Discord Role by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457916/get-a-discord-role-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the code.

`YOUR_GUILD_ID` should be the ID of your guild/server.

```py
if message.guild.id == YOUR_GUILD_ID:
    if message.content.startswith("&ign "):
        # ...
        await message.author.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, id=991038550118121602))
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I've just tried implementing this into my code and get the following error.

File "main.py", line 31, in on_message
    await message.author.remove_roles(get(message.author.roles, id=991038550118121602))
NameError: name 'get' is not defined

Have I not imported something?

Comment: Any clue how I'd fix this error?

Comment: I fixed to get to discord.utils.get it should work now